# Extract json object data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a table in which a columns contains data in json object

```
[
    { "Name":"no note",
      "Code":"no note",
      "Note":"",
      "Description":"no note"
    }, 
    { 
       "Name":"sfsdfs",
       "Code":"sfdsfsdf",
       "Note":"fsdfsdf",
       "Description":"sfdfdsfdsfsdf"
    }
]
```

I have to extract data from these objects and insert into a temptable along with some primary value Like `EntryId`

```
EntryId | Name | Note | Description
```

Please suggest any solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's wrong with `OPENJSON`?

Comment: i have tried <br/>
<code>SELECT * OPENJSON(PunchDetails.ReasonCodes)
  WITH (
    Name NVARCHAR(510) '$.Name',
    Code NVARCHAR(510) '$.Code',
    Note NVARCHAR(510) '$.Note',
    Description NVARCHAR(510) '$.Description',
    
  )</code><br/>

because i have a row corresponding to each EntryId so i have to fetch that data from table and put that into openjson function but actually query is select * from Openjson

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you have tried. Comments aren't a suitable place for code samples.

Comment: [Edit] your question, with the code, and explain why it doesn't work. In terms of that statement, what is `PunchDetails.ReasonCodes`, as no object with the name/alias `PunchDetails` is declared in your query.

Comment: Actually i have ReasonCodes column in PunchDetails table that i have passed to the openjson function

Comment: @Cipher What are the expected values for the `EntryId` column?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your statement and add additional `APPLY` operator:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE PunchDetails (ReasonCodes nvarchar(1000))
INSERT INTO PunchDetails (ReasonCodes)
VALUES (N'[
    { "Name":"no note",
      "Code":"no note",
      "Note":"",
      "Description":"no note"
    }, 
    { 
       "Name":"sfsdfs",
       "Code":"sfdsfsdf",
       "Note":"fsdfsdf",
       "Description":"sfdfdsfdsfsdf"
    }
]')
```

Statement:

```
-- INSERT INTO TempTable (Name, Code, Note, Description)
SELECT j.Name, j.Code, j.Note, j.Description
FROM PunchDetails p
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(p.ReasonCodes) WITH ( 
   Name NVARCHAR(510) '$.Name', 
   Code NVARCHAR(510) '$.Code', 
   Note NVARCHAR(510) '$.Note', 
   Description NVARCHAR(510) '$.Description'
) j
```